# SciPy numerical integration routine returns a negative absolute error estimate

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

Sometimes [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns a **negative** estimate of the absolute error in the result. For example,

```py
import scipy.integrate

def f(x):
    ep = 1e-5
    return (1 / (x - 0.5 + 1j * ep) ** 2).real

print(scipy.integrate.quad(f, 0, 1))
```

gives (note the sign of the second value, the estimate of the absolute error)

```
(-3.999999991409368, -7.111460202240431e-08)
```

This result was obtained with SciPy 1.8.0, Python 3.10.2, x86_64 GNU/Linux; the analytical value is -10000000000/2500000001 = -3.99999999840000...

I guess something may go wrong (with a very sharp peak in the integrand), but what does the negative sign in front of the absolute error estimate exactly mean?

I am also worried about the error estimate code of `nquad`:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/b5d8bab88af61d61de09641243848df63380a67f/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py#L890

which takes `max(self.abserr, abserr)` but it may not work if `abserr` could be negative.

Comment: It turned out that negative signs of error estimates for my real problem at hand were due to my stupid mistake; my problem solved. Now, the above simplified, artificial example is the only example I know that gives a negative estimate of the absolute error.

Answer (score 0):

That may be a numerical issue as I did not see it referenced anywhere. You could put in `, points = [0.5]` to specify the sharp peak, which seems to be able to solve the issue and return a positive error estimate.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the use of the `points` option, which will be useful for some cases. The above example was artificially made just for demonstration purposes; real problems may have more complicated integrands whose positions of peaks are unknown (possibly in a multidimensional space; `nquad` calls `quad`). It would be appreciated if someone could answer the origin of the negative absolute errors (intentional?, bug? numerical issue?, documented in somewhere?) and how one should interpret them (`abs(abserr)` is still reliable, not so reliable or completely wrong, etc.).

Comment: I think it is not itentional, referring to the note at the bottom of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Comment: Hmmm... these difficult examples in the reference manual still give positive (or zero) absolute error estimates... It is still unclear to me how come it that the absolute error could be negative and whether it could be fixed/improved.